# Cloudflare DNS with Sub Domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, cloudflare

We swithced our main domain that was pointing at an AWS ec2 server to a Cloudflare pages site and created a new sub domain to point to the site on the ec2 server

I created an A record with the IP address of the ec2 server and also tried a CNAME record with the  Public IPv4 DNS but both get redirected to the main domain

Is there a configuration I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe your page does the redirect. Check the exact headers of the redirection response.

Comment: That was it, thanks @CherryDT